# Bind9 DNS - How to redirect domain to another domain

Tags: linux, networking, domain-name-system, debian, bind

I'm trying to redirect facebook.com ( and all subdomains ) to google.com, however I appear to be missing something.

```
zone "facebook.com" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/nene-block";
};
```

That is my named.conf.local

nene-block:http://pastebin.com/DQmj8huw

Basically, what I want to do is redirect users who go to facebook to google. I've been trying for hours but I can't find a solution.

With these settings, I get DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN in Chrome

Comment: You are not authoritative for facebook.com. How do you try to deal with that? Also, the AAAA records you show are obviously not valid.

Comment: If you're speaking about `http` and `https` traffic, which you want to redirect to Google: You'll get `Privacy errors` in `Chrome`, because the supplied cert doesn't match the hostname, you're using to access the website.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use [this example code from JISC](https://community.jisc.ac.uk/library/janet-services-documentation/how-block-or-sinkhole-domains-bind) to spoof Facebook DNS. I see a few possible problems.

1. Have you tested your BIND setup to see if it works at all? Create some simple records on it for local addresses first, before trying Facebook.
2. Your SOA record is confusing. You're saying that the authoritative DNS is found at www.facebook.com, not your own server. What is your local server name, BTW?
3. AAAA records are for IPv6 but you have IPv4 in them. You should probably omit AAAA until you have a better handle on the other parts.
4. If this is intended as an actual method of blocking users from reaching Facebook, not just a personal experiment, then it won't work. Users can just [switch to external DNS](https://www.google.com/search?q=DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN).